# There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, deep-learning, macos-catalina, bert-language-model

[image]I am using MacOS & used DistilBert model using Sentence Transformer for chatbot implementation and generated the API in VS code.

But after giving 3 inputs it pop’s up this error:

UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '

I tried to downgrade the python version 3.9 to 3.7 but it didn't worked.

Comment: That's a warning. It shouldn't stop your program from running. It might indicate a different problem though.

Comment: Actually, my output is fetching the semantic records from the dataset provided in model.So it is not able to display the matched records.

Comment: If so, the error is somewhere else

Comment: As mentioned above, warnings do not prevent you from running the program. Provide some more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am building question answers chatbot which are  stored as greetings in Json format &  suggestions as a final output in the dataframes & I am using pretrained distilbert but when I run it on local machine to check the response from postman it gives output for single input but after that this error pop's followed by closing the server.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with PyTorch mps while running `tqdm=4.65.0`. I was able to remove it and install 4.66.1 which solved it. Not a RAM issue.